# Can an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project reference and instantiate a Windows Forms class Library that references a System.Windows.Forms control?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I am porting a legacy .NET 4.x Web API and class library to .NET 7. The class library served the Windows and web environments, and has public classes that have function overloads that make use of Windows Forms controls and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext` items.

I upgraded the class library to a Windows Forms class library project template and then added the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` to access the web stuff.

When a add reference to the class library in Web API, it works.

However, when I attempt to instantiate the class library I get an error like:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e

Is it not possible to access the full .NET Core (Windows Forms) environment from a web project?

I can reference the DLL, but when I instantiate the class, I get that error.

Comment: You can reference a WinForms class library in a ASP.NET Web app, however I cannot easily imagine a valid usage scenario for using a WinForms control in a ASP.NET Web App. But the key point is you need to make sure both projects are using `<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>` target framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a WinForms class library in a ASP.NET Web app, however I cannot easily imagine a valid usage scenario for using a WinForms control in a ASP.NET Web App. But the key point is you need to make sure both projects are using `<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>` target framework.

**Example**

In the following example, in the web app, I'll instantiate a custom control that I have in a class library, then I just use `DrawToBitmap` method of the custom control, to create an image and later I'll show the image in a web page.

Here is a step-by-step example:

1. Create a ASP.NET Core Web App project, choose .NET 7, and name it as Net7WebApplication.
2. Edit the project file, and change the target framework to `<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>`. (You can do the same in project properties page)
3. Add a new WinForms Control Library .NET project, choose .NET 7, and name it as Net7WinFormsLibrary.
4. Modify the class1.cs to the following code:

   ```
   namespace Net7WinFormsLibrary
   {
       public class MyControl : Control
       {
           public MyControl()
           {
               this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
           }
           protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
           {
               e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Red);
               TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Hello, World!",
                   new Font("Segoe UI", 10), ClientRectangle, Color.Blue);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Add reference of the WinForms project to the Web Project.
6. Modify Index.cshtml.cs to the following:

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
   using System.Drawing;
   using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

   namespace Net7WebApplication.Pages
   {
       public class IndexModel : PageModel
       {
           private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

           public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
           {
               _logger = logger;
           }
           public string ImageSrc { get; set; }
           public void OnGet()
           {
               var c = new Net7WinFormsLibrary.MyControl();
               using (var bm = new Bitmap(200, 200))
               {
                   c.DrawToBitmap(bm, c.ClientRectangle);
                   var bytes = (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bm, typeof(byte[]));
                   ImageSrc = $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. Modify the Index.cshtml to the following:

   ```
   @page
   @model IndexModel
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
   }

   <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
       <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

       <img src="@Model.ImageSrc" />
   </div>
   ```
8. Save everything and run the project. There you go!

   [image]